# Express serving angular routes

Tags: angular, express

I am trying to get my angular routes working in express so far it will load the page index.html and if you navigate from there it will use the routes just fine, however if you open a new browser and try to go directly to a route ('deep link') it will not work... (the routes do work in ng serve)

here's what i'm using to get it to serve the index.html

```
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
    app.use("*",function(req,res){
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"/dist/index.html"));
    });
```

If i try to go to localhost:3000 it works fine... again as i navigate from that page those routes work fine too but if i try to do localhost:3000/room/3290sfda9328fa98 (that page contains a route :id) then it does not work

Here is the angular side of the routes

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: StartscreenComponent },
  { path: 'room/:id', component: RoomComponent },
  { path: 'createroom', component: StartroomComponent }
];
```

The error you get back looks like this:

```
ReferenceError: path is not defined
    at /Documents/angular8/nodechat/index.js:18:18
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Documents/angular8/nodechat/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Documents/angular8/nodechat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Documents/angular8/nodechat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at param (/Documents/angular8/nodechat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/Documents/angular8/nodechat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/Documents/angular8/nodechat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
    at next (/Documents/angular8/nodechat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (/Documents/angular8/nodechat/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
    at SendStream.emit (events.js:189:13)
```

Here is a bit more of the index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
// const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
const helmet = require('helmet');
app.use(helmet());
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
app.use("*",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"/dist/index.html"));
});
http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: When you say `It doesn't work` what does that look like? Do you get an error?

Comment: good point @quicklikerabbit

Comment: I don't really use Angular, but have you tried putting a / infront of every path? React router requires you to do this i.e) path="/" or path="/room/:id"

Comment: @Jpark9061 adding the leading slashes breaks the routes in angular 9 ... so not sure that's still the case.

Comment: Could you post your index.js file? Just wondering what line 18 looks like; seems like there's a variable called `path` that isn't defined.

Comment: @quicklikerabbit line 18 is actually above where it says 
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"/dist/index.html"));

Comment: Are you `require`ing `path` at the top of your index file?

Comment: @quicklikerabbit no let me update to show more of the index.js

Comment: @quicklikerabbit THAT was the problem ...  it needed 
const path = require('path');

Comment: I had a feeling ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `require(path)` before you can use it. Add this to the top of your `index.js`:

```
const path = require('path')
```

Comment: My hero! thank you... it's my first time working with express and angular so it's been a learning curve for sure.

Comment: My pleasure! Lots to learn with both frameworks, but you're off to a good start. Don't forget to 'Accept' this answer if feel it answered your question. Let's other's know that this question has been resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be becuase you're directly serving the index.html file. Try this?

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"/dist/"));
```

or

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"/dist"));
```

Comment: nah... didn't work :( I just tried it but I think i had tried it before and then my thought was mayybe if i specified the index file it would work since angular is largely looking for the routes anyway but clearly the server wants something too